Intermediate Schauder estimates on initial boundary problem of second order parabolic PDE
In Krylov's Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Hölder Spaces (1996), Theorem 9.2.3 states a Schauder-type estimate for initial boundary value problems.
Theorem 9.2.3:
Let $Q = (0, T) \times \mathbb{R}^d$ be a domain, and let
\begin{align}
L = a^{ij} D_{ij} + b^i D_i + c
\end{align}
be a second-order uniformly elliptic operator with coefficients satisfying:

Hölder Continuity: For some $\delta \in (0, 1)$ and constant $K > 0$:
\begin{align}
   \|a^{ij}\|_{C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q)} + \|b^i\|_{C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q)} + \|c\|_{C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q)} \leq K,
   \end{align}
where $C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q)$ denotes the parabolic Hölder space over $Q$.

Uniform Ellipticity: There exists $\kappa > 0$ such that for all $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $(t, x) \in Q$:
\begin{align}
   a^{ij}(t, x) \xi_i \xi_j \geq \kappa |\xi|^2.
   \end{align}

Lower Order Term: The coefficient $c(t, x)$ satisfies:
\begin{align}
   c(t, x) \leq -\lambda \quad \text{for all } (t, x) \in Q,
   \end{align}
for some constant $\lambda > 0$.


Let $g \in C^{2 + \delta}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $f \in C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q)$. Then there exists a unique function $u \in C^{1 + \delta/2, 2 + \delta}(Q)$ satisfying:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u = Lu + f & \text{in } Q, \\
u(0, x) = g(x) & \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}^d.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Moreover, there exists a constant $N = N(d, \delta, K, \kappa, \lambda)$ such that:
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{C^{1 + \delta/2, 2 + \delta}(Q)} \leq N \left( \|f\|_{C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q)} + \|g\|_{C^{2 + \delta}(\mathbb{R}^d)} \right).
\end{align}

My questions are:

Dependence on $T$: Is $N$ independent of $T$?

Interior Estimate: If $N$ is independent of $T$, can we, using Example 9.2.5 and Theorem 9.2.3, obtain an interior estimate:
\begin{align}
   \|u\|_{C^{1 + \delta/2, 2 + \delta}(Q_1)} \leq N \left( \|Lu - \partial_t u\|_{C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q_2)} + \|u\|_{L^\infty(Q_2)} + \|u(0, \cdot)\|_{C^{2 + \delta}(B_2)} \right),
   \end{align}
where:

$Q_R = (0, T) \times B_R$ with $B_R$ being the ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$,
The constant $N = N(d, \delta, K, \kappa, \lambda)$ remains independent of $T$.


Intermediate Schauder Estimates: Are there results on intermediate Schauder estimates (allowing less regularity in time $t$ such as in Knerr, 1980), specifically estimates of the form:
\begin{align}
   &\sum_{j=0}^{2} \|D^j u\|_{C^{\delta/2, \delta}(Q_1)} + \sup_{t \in [0, T]} \left\| \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(\cdot, t) \right\|_{C^{\delta}(B_1)} \\
   &\leq N \left( \|u(0, \cdot)\|_{C^{2 + \delta}(B_2)} + \sup_{t \in [0, T]} \left[ \|u(\cdot, t)\|_{L^\infty(B_2)} + \|f(\cdot, t)\|_{C^{\delta}(B_2)} \right] \right),
   \end{align}
where $N = N(d, \delta, K, \kappa, \lambda)$?



I would appreciate any insights or references regarding these questions.
